# Are there classes for managing HTML objects in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

Is there an HTML DOM object model structure in .Net? nothing that is specific to MVC or WebControls but just for HTML document management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or [CsQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/) if you're more familiar with Jquery.